# How to use Grammar::Tracer with a unit scoped grammar?

Tags: grammar, raku

I am using [Grammar::Tracer](https://github.com/jnthn/grammar-debugger) with the following setup:

**p.p6**

```
use v6;
use lib '.';
use MyGrammar;
my $res = MyGrammar.parse('hello 6 9 bye');
say $res;
```

**MyGrammar.pm6**:

```
unit grammar MyGrammar;
use Grammar::Tracer;

rule TOP { [<number> || <word> ]* }
rule number { \d+ }
rule word { \w+}
```

But the tracing is not enabled. I guess it is because the grammer `MyGrammar` is not in the lexical scope of the `use Grammar::Tracer` statement?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `Grammar::Tracer` module works by exporting a custom metaclass to be used in place of the default one for the `grammar` keyword. This must already be in place before the keyword `grammar` is encountered, since that is when we resolve and commit to the metaclass to be used for the type being declared.

The solution is to put the `use` statement ahead of the `grammar` declaration:

```
use Grammar::Tracer;
unit grammar MyGrammar;
```